# Validate Date for eligibility above 18 year's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have used the following for date input

```
<tr>
<td>Date of Birth :</td>
<td><input type="date" name="dob" required="required" /></td>
```

I want to validate the Date of birth whether it's above 18 years or not. I have no idea how to code for that.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the min attribute, [see](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date), take into account that it might not be supported in all browsers, and that you should validate the date on server side:

```
<input type="date" name="dob" required="required" min="2000-02-23"/>
```

If you use php you can do something like this:

```
$today = new \DateTime();
$minDate = $today->modify('-18 years');

echo '<input type="date" name="dob" required="required" min="' . $minDate->format('Y-m-d') . '"/>'
```

Comment: So are you going to change min value everyday in html?

Comment: @Durga offcourse not, that's why I show how to use the min attribute and give an example with php

Answer (score 1):

One of the way for client side validation is using JavaScript. You can use the below for basic validation which always can be further enhanced for more use cases.

```
<td><input type="date" name="dob" required="required" onchange="validateAge(this)" /></td>



<script type="text/javaScript">

function validateAge(age) {
    var input = age.value;
    if(input>=18) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        alert("Invalid Age"+input);
        return false;
    }
}

</script>
```